# How do you run WebGL & JavaScript at server-side?

Tags: azure, three.js, webgl, server-side, serverside-javascript

I am currently working on a Three.js based WebGL project and I need to get a screenshot of a given model quickly when needed.

I have implemented some JavaScript code that will render a 3D model then return a picture of it. But the problem is that the JavaScript code runs at client side, but I need it to make it server-side, so I can get the picture by a URL (such as example.com/get-screenshot.php?id=2) and serve it to my users.

I am wondering if there is a mechanism that will automatically trigger the job and return what I need. Besides the server that hosts my site, which is Azure website, I also have access to an Azure virtual machine with Windows Server or Ubuntu Server installed; I don't know if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about take the screenshot on the user's machine using `canvas.toDataURL` and upload it to the server?

Comment: @gman Yes that is exactly what I am doing right now.

Comment: It sounds like a lot of work but ... If you build [chromium](http://chromium.org) from source you can also build the software version of mesa. It's checked into chromium's source and is used for testing on servers without GPUs. You can then run Chromium without a GPU and use all the GPU features. You need to pass in `--use-gl=osmesa` and you probably also have to pass in `--ignore-gpu-blacklist`. So, you might be able to shell to chromium in your server? You might also be able to force DirectX into software mode since you're on Windows without re-compiling Chrome. Ask the *angleproject* guys.

Answer (score 2):

Your WebGL code needs a GPU to run; Amazon recently introduced a GPU instance to EC2, but Azure currently does not have that option.

The next release of the Verold platform gives you a full Three.js editor with hosting options for your web 3D desktop and mobile apps. You will be able to implement this usecase on our platform. Send an email to info@verold.com for details.

Ross

Answer (score -1):

You can try use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) with [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [node](http://nodejs.org) to genarate those images.

phantomjs can simulate a full stack browser enironment, and can run on server side.

Comment: But it can't simulate a GPU when none exists.